# Dynamic URL hyperlink on dynamic Image

Tags: php, image, redirect

I am developing a script that will let users put a image on a website that rotates periodically. The website only lets them put one image that can be linked to one url.

The image is randomly selected among a set of previously submitted user images. Image is served through a php script so only one `<img scr="http://...image.php?id=xxx">` tag will serve all users' images.

I have links that are associated with each image like this.

- image_xxx_1.png - www.domain.com/one
- image_xxx_2.png - www.domain.com/two
- image_xxx_n.png - www.domain.com/some

Now, I have to redirect the visitors who clicks on the image to the corresponding URLs. The problem is that I can have only a fixed url which users will click, one for every user but not every image. So, how will I get my script to know which image was clicked on resulting to which URL to redirect the user to ?

-NOTE : No JS can be used on the page. Only one image and one link.

If it helps, I will be using CodeIgniter (PHP 5.5.5).

Comment: Use random. And write code.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have an array which looks something like like:

```
array(
  1 => 'http://www.domain.com/one',
  2 => 'http://www.domain.com/two'
)
```

And this is randomised on each page visit. You could save that array to SESSION, then change the link to point to an image click handler e.g.

Inside the view page you add:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['image_links'] = $image_map_array;
```

Inside click.php you have:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['image_links'][$_REQUEST['id']])) {
  header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['image_links'][$_REQUEST['id']]);
  exit;
}
```

This will redirect the user to the matching location for that ID, based on the random image map you made earlier.

Comment: But I have no control over the page on which the images are displayed. I can only put AN image & link it A url.